# How to smooth the curve

Tags: plotting

I use mathematica 12.3

```mathematica
(*单位约定：时间\[LongDash]s; 频率\[LongDash]MHz;长度-m*)
Clear["Global`*"]
cc = 300;(*光速*)
\[Omega] = 2*\[Pi]*351.722*10^6;(*光频*)

k = \[Omega]/cc;(*光波矢*)
L = 10*10^(-3);(*铯泡长度*)

NN = 4*10^15;(*25摄氏度时铯原子的原子数密度*)
\[HBar] = 
  1.055*10^(-34);(*约化普朗克常量*)
\[Epsilon] = 
  8.854*10^(-12);(*真空介电常数*)
\[Sigma] = 4.64*10^(-29);(*铯原子D1线的偶极矩阵元*)

m = 2.207*10^(-25);(*铯原子质量，单位：kg*)

kB = 1.381*10^(-35);(*玻尔兹曼常量，已换算成我们的单位制*)
T = 273.15 + 25;(*温度*)

Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], 1] = 0;
Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], 2] = 2*\[Pi]*5.2;(*2态的decay rate*)

Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], 3] = 2*\[Pi]*0.03;
Subscript[\[Gamma], 
  21] = (Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], 2] + Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], 
     1])/2;(*2态和1态之间的off-diagonal decay rate*)

Subscript[\[Gamma], 
  31] = (Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], 3] + Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], 
     1])/2;
Subscript[\[CapitalOmega], c] = 2*\[Pi]*10;(*耦合光的拉比频率*)

Subscript[\[CapitalOmega], p] = 2*\[Pi]*3;(*探针光的拉比频率*)

v = 10^(-6)*\[Mu];        
Subscript[\[Delta], p] = 0;
Subscript[\[Delta], c] = 2*\[Pi]*\[Nu];
Subscript[\[CapitalDelta], p] = Subscript[\[Delta], p] + k*v;
Subscript[\[CapitalDelta], c] = Subscript[\[Delta], c] - k*v;
\[Chi] = (
  I*(NN*\[Sigma]^2)/(\[Epsilon]*\[HBar])*10^(-6))/((Subscript[\[Gamma]\
, 21] - I*Subscript[\[CapitalDelta], p]) + (\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[CapitalOmega]\), \(c\), \(2\)]/
      4\))/(Subscript[\[Gamma], 31] - 
      I*(Subscript[\[CapitalDelta], p] + Subscript[\[CapitalDelta], 
         c])));(*极化率*)

Im\[Chi] = 
  FullSimplify[Im[\[Chi]], 
   Assumptions -> {Subscript[\[Delta], c] \[Element] 
      Reals, \[Mu] \[Element] Reals}];
f = 10^(-6)*(m/(2*\[Pi]*kB*T))^(1/2)*
   Exp[(-m*v^2)/(2*kB*T)];(*麦克斯韦速度分布*)
\[Mu]M = 500;(*原子速度，计算范围*)

d\[Mu] = 0.5;(*原子速度，计算步长*)

DIm\[Chi] = Sum[Im\[Chi]*f, {\[Mu], -\[Mu]M, \[Mu]M, d\[Mu]}]*d\[Mu];
FT = Exp[-DIm\[Chi]*k*L];(*透射光强*)
\[Nu]M = 10;(*作图范围*)
ITMin = 0;
a = Plot[FT, {\[Nu], -\[Nu]M, \[Nu]M}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-\[Nu]M, \[Nu]M}, {0, 1}}, 
   AxesOrigin -> {-\[Nu]M, ITMin}];
Show[a, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Thick, 
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 20, Thick], 
 FrameLabel -> {Coupling frequency detuning @MHz, 
   Free space Transmission@arb . units }, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 20, Thick]]
```

get this

[image]

but I use mathematica 10.3 can get complete

[image]

To figure out why, I notice that the core of this diagram is `Exp[-DIm\[Chi]*k*L]`,So I use `Table` and `ListPlot`

`Table[Exp[-DIm\[Chi]*k*L], {\[Nu], -10, 10, 0.01}] //  ListPlot[#, PlotRange -> All] &`

get this

[image]

You can see that the dots in the middle are very sparse，How do I deal with that in 12.3?

Comment: I am not good with plotting, but have you tried the `Plot[...,PlotPoints->...]` option?

Comment: @user293787 it also too bad,I have try `PlotPoints->5000`,it also not good

Comment: Indeed, `Plot[FT, {ν, -νM, νM}, PlotRange -> {{-νM, νM}, {0, 1}}, AxesOrigin -> {-νM, ITMin}, Exclusions -> None]` solves the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you replace your definition of `Im\[Chi]` with

```
Im\[Chi] = 
  FullSimplify[Im[\[Chi]], 
   Assumptions -> {Subscript[\[Delta], c] \[Element] 
      Reals, \[Mu] \[Element] Reals}] // ComplexExpand;
```

then it will work. All I did was to add  `// ComplexExpand` at the end.